# Vue.js - How to use iView in RTL direction?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating an Arabic website with 'Vue.js', and I use `iView` for UI components, but the problem is that it's designed for `LTR` layouts while Arabic is `RTL`. **How can I convert iView components to RTL??**

Example: I want to make the search button in the input field on the left in this [website](https://fields-combined.firebaseapp.com/#/) "it's now on the right"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `dir='rtl'` attribute like `<i-input dir="rtl" .../>` but the problem is with the search button which will not fit appropriately, so to fix that add some CSS rules like i did in the following working example :

```js
var Main = {

}

var Component = Vue.extend(Main)
new Component().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/iview/dist/styles/iview.css");
#app {
  padding: 32px;
}



.ivu-input-group-append,
.ivu-input-group>.ivu-input:last-child {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px!important;
 
}
.ivu-input-search::before{
width:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/iview/dist/iview.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <i-input search enter-button search placeholder="ابحث عن طريق الإسم أو المدينة" dir="rtl" />

  </div>
</div>
```