# Add dir rtl attribute to html tag in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a vue project using `vue create` command .
I want to add attribute `dir="rtl"` to my html tag.
in `Nuxt.js` we do that:

```
<template>
    <div>Main View</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'app',
    head: {
        htmlAttrs: {
          lang: 'fa',
          dir: 'rtl'
        },
    }
</script>
```

but in Vuejs This does not work. how can i do this?

Comment: There is no equivalent for Vue apps. Your directory structure is flattened by Webpack, and everything goes to the client in generated .js files. What are you trying to achieve with the dir attribute in a vue app?

Comment: you could specify it to the root element or like i did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089736/iview-how-to-use-in-rtl-layout/53104786#53104786)

Comment: @bbsimonbb i want to create a Persian language App with vue and need to set lang="fa" to document html tag. also i want to set all elements in rtl mode (Because Persian is a rtl language)

Comment: :-) google "vue i18n", or look at the vuei18n plugin. There are solutions out there, but they don't involve the dir property as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put this configuration inside the `created` hook of Vue instance as follows :

```
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
     ...

    created(){
       let htmlEl=document.querySelector("html");
        htmlEl.setAttribute('dir','rtl');
        htmlEl.setAttribute('lang','fa');
      }
   })
```